# Error running rails generate devise User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hey I am new to rails and I am getting this error whenever I try to run

```
rails generate devise User
```

I get this error in there terminal:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007fcad64c5e20 @paths=["/Users/DavidStevenson/Desktop/omrails/omrails/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fcad64c5d80>]> (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/DavidStevenson/Desktop/omrails/omrails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have looked in the routes.rb file and could not see anything apparently wrong. When I comment out the line:

```
devise_for :installs
```

I can run the server again. Any thoughts why this would happen?

Comment: I was able to solve this by doing the following: I commented out the line devise_for :installs, in the routes.rb file and re-ran rails generate devise:install it corrected all errors.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why do you use ruby 1.9.3 instead of 2.0 ?
Secondly, why do you use rails 4.0.0.rc2 instead of its stable release 4.0 ?

For your question,

devise requires `devise_for :users` in your routes.rb file. It must be same as your resource name. Use `user` both in routes.rb and at your generator.

Comment: I didn't "use" your solution, but it was correct thanks! after re-running rails generate devise:install it correctly installed everything, and I updated my rails gem for 4.0.0, I am using ruby 1.9.3 for compatibility for a tutorial I am using.

Comment: Nice to hear it's solved. Uhmm... a correct answer would deserve accepting, eh?

Answer (score 1):

I found this error after migrating from Active Record to MongoID, the problem is that the Devise initializer (`config/initializers/devise.rb`) specifies the ORM (line 25 for me):

```
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
```

I just only needed to replace this line with:

```
require 'devise/orm/mongoid'
```

Now is working :)